# What does the equation $x^2+24xy+68y^2=0$ represent?

Tags: calculus

The equation $x^2+24xy+68y^2=0$ represents a

1. Ellips
2. Parabola
3. Hyperbola
4. Can't be decided

I know the general equations of all of these geometric figures, but I can't rework the given equation to match any of them. Completing the square w.r.t. $x$, I get $$(x+12y)^2-76y^2 = 0,$$

but it's still not on any desired form.

Comment: Where is the equation? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Identifying_rotated_conic_sections

Comment: Cool, so $B^2-4AC=24^2-4\cdot68=576-272=304>0 \Rightarrow \text{Hyperbola}.$ But how should I solve this problem without knowing this handy formula? EDITED.

Comment: But this is not  non-degenerate conic section

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what non-degenerate is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Completing the square w.r.t $x$ i get $$(x+12y)^2-76y^2 \color{red}{=0}$$

This is a good step; now rewrite using $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ to get:
$$\left(x+12y + \sqrt{76}y \right)\left(x+12y - \sqrt{76}y \right)=0$$
But this implies:
$$x+12y + \sqrt{76}y = 0 \;\vee\; x+12y - \sqrt{76}y = 0$$
And these are equations of...?

Comment: Straight lines? $x+y(12+\sqrt{76})=0\Leftrightarrow y=-\frac{1}{12+\sqrt{76}}x.$

Comment: @Parseval Indeed: two straight lines, intersecting in the origin. It is a so called [_degenerate_ conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic).

Comment: But the correct answer is hyperbola.

Comment: @Parseval Yes, two intersecting lines is the degenerate form of a hyperbola.

Comment: What is meant by degenerate and non degenerate? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @Parseval You can look up the definitions (see link above). Without getting technical: _non degenerate_ refers to "real conics", i.e. a proper ellipse, parabola or hyperbola; the _degenerate_ ones refer to the special cases such as intersecting lines (e.g. $x^2-y^2=0$) and parallel lines (e.g. $x^2=1$).